# Oauth signature failed for withings API

Tags: java, spring, rest, withings

I am working to integrate my application with the Withings api with spring rest template.

But,while generating the Oauth signature I am getting the "Invalid signature". I am trying to devise a signature according to the API specification but I am not able to generate it successfully. I have mentioned the code that I used. Please, provide me some solutions.

```
private String generateSignature(String baseString, String secret) throws          UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String secretKey = consumerSecret + "&";


    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1SignatureMethod.SIGNATURE_NAME);
    HMAC_SHA1SignatureMethod hmacsha = new HMAC_SHA1SignatureMethod(keySpec);
    String signatureString = hmacsha.sign(baseString);
    String base64Encode = new String((signatureString.getBytes()));
    signature = URLEncoder.encode(base64Encode, "UTF-8");
```

For reference, http://oauth.withings.com/api

Comment: I am doing through google oauth.. In scribe all the supported domain like facebook, twitter is maintion but withings api is not maintion. So, how you are able to do the authentication part.. please do share with me.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issues before , it seems the signature need you params ( api params + oauth params ) to be ordered alphabetically .

You need also to give a correct secret word in making you signature based uri .

you can check if you want my php oauth lib ( more particulary in AbstractService.php ) for withing here 
https://github.com/huitiemesens/PHPoAuthLib ( it s a fork of the original phpoauthlib with specific order for withings apis ... )